# Ubuntu 18.04 Gdm theme change

Tags: 18.04, gdm

I want to change my login theme. I'v downloaded theme from gnome-look, and I can't find proper tutorial how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @abu_bua I was checking that, it doesn't help me

Comment: It is not trivial to change the GDM theme if I look at this: https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/wiki/GDM-Theme

Comment: @PatrykMandark can you share the link to gdm3 you are trying to install?

Comment: @PRATAP https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1010611/  for example that

Comment: @PatrykMandark the theme you have provided is for MDM (Mint Display Manager). It is not possible to install in GDM (Gnome Display Manager)

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, my bad. I will link proper one